# django lookup function bug to extract year and week from date

Tags: django

I have defined two django lookup functions

```
@models.DateTimeField.register_lookup
class ExtractYear(Extract):
    lookup_name = 'year'

@models.DateTimeField.register_lookup    
class ExtractWeek(Extract):
    lookup_name = 'week'
```

I have call it like so :

```
propositions = propositions.annotate(week=ExtractWeek('posting_date'), year=ExtractYear('posting_date'))
```

It gives : Year 2017 , Week : 52 for the date 01/01/2017

I have +5 hours trying to figure out the problem source, who can investigate this ?

Comment: Post the database you're using and the resultant sql (`str(propositions.query)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO week year numbering differs from 'regular' year numbering around the turn of the year. The date `2017-01-01` is in ISO week 52 of ISO year 2016. See the wikipedia article on [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for more info.

You are getting the unexpected result year 2017, week 52 because `year` extracts the calendar year, but `week` returns the ISO week.

You haven't said which database you are using. In postgres, you could use `isoyear` to get the ISO year for a date.

```
@models.DateTimeField.register_lookup
class ExtractISOYear(Extract):
    lookup_name = 'isoyear'
```

The following query would return iso_year 2016, week 52:

```
propositions = propositions.annotate(week=ExtractWeek('posting_date'), iso_year=ExtractISOYear('posting_date'))
```